# Does anyone know where to get a bluetooth module and how to program it

Tags: iphone, programming-languages, bluetooth, ipod-touch

I need a bluetooth module or chip/board that is compatable with Apple products such as iPhones. I also need to help with programming it. Please help. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a module you can try this .. http://www.connectblue.com/products/bluetooth-products/bluetooth-modules/bluetooth-iphone-ios-accessory-module-obs414/

Or alternatively you can go for a generic solution like http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/MSP430BT5190%2BCC2560_Bluetooth_Platform_FAQ
and add the MFi in your product. 
You can get commercial support from TI and MindTree on this solution (including MFi support)